# How to use object rest with generics in flow?

Tags: javascript, generics, types, flowtype

I am using flow and have a function that takes an object, and returns an array that splits that object into two objects based on the properties of that object.

The definition of this function looks like as following:

```
function split({ foo, bar, ...params }) {
  return [
   { foo, bar },
   params
  ]
}
```

and would be used like this:

```
split({ foo: 123, bar: 456, baz: 'abc' }) // [{ foo: 123, bar: 456 }, { baz: 'abc' }]
```

I am not sure how to go about adding flow definitions for this function where `foo` and `bar` are constant, known properties that I want to extract, and the `params` is a generic type that could be anything.

My current attempt is the following:

```
type FooBar = { foo: number, bar: number }

function split<T>({ foo, bar, ...params }: FooBar & T): [FooBar, T] {
  return [
   { foo, bar },
   params
  ]
}
```

however, flow interprets the second element of the return array as still having all properties that were passed in originally. How do I tell flow that the second element only has the properties that AREN'T foo and bar?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
type FooBar = { foo: number, bar: number };

function split<T: FooBar>({ foo, bar, ...params }: T): [FooBar, $Diff<T, FooBar>] {
  return [
   { foo, bar },
   params
  ];
}
```

Comment: Hm, maybe I misunderstand this syntax: `<T: FooBar>` but I thought that would mean `T` is given a type of `FooBar` so there would be no valid values that params could be if we are already destructuring `foo` and `bar` out.

Comment: `FooBar` in this case is not an exact type. All it means is that the input argument conforms to the shape `{ foo: number, bar: number }`. An an example, `{ foo: number, bar: number, baz: string }` correctly conforms to the shape defined as `T` in this case.